# Change field in Record

Tags: java, reflection, record

I study reflection and try to change field's value in Record.

```
public record Account(Integer id, String login, Boolean blocked) {}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account(null, null, null);
        setFieldValue(account, "id", 1);
        setFieldValue(account, "login", "admin");
        setFieldValue(account, "blocked", false);
        System.out.println(account);
    }
    public static void setFieldValue(Object instance,
                                     String fieldName,
                                     Object value) {
        try {
            Field field = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(instance, value);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I convert Record to Class everything works, but with Record I get Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set final java.lang.Integer field Account.id to java.lang.Integer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:80)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:799)
```

What do I have to do to make the code work with records?

Comment: You create a new record with the changes you want. You CAN NOT change an already existing instance.

Comment: What you want is impossible. `record` objects are immutable. At best, you can make __a new__ instance of `Account` with the changes applied. If the `Account` object is stored somewhere, you can then overwrite the field (if it isn't `final`) of whatever is storing the Account with this new account instance.

Comment: Hotspot trusts the final fields in a record - this is why you can't change them. See the specification for [`Field.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object%29) - "If the underlying field is final, this Field object has write access if and only if the following conditions are met: ... the field's declaring class is not a record class."

Comment: What about...initializing the fields in the constructor?

Comment: @dan1st I was hoping to implement my own ORM (for practice) and create records with data from the database. But record will have links to other records and a list of records, and then I'll have to turn record creation inside out. It's harder, I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: See the [definition of record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

Comment: No, for creating a `record` from a database row, you don’t have to turn the creation inside out. You have to stop turning it inside out. Being widespread doesn’t turn a bad practice into a good one.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In general the commenters saying that this "can't be done" or is "impossible" aren't wrong... unless you are willing to slightly bend the rules of the JVM :)  For example, by using unsafe reflection to change the relevant value directly at the memory location in the record like this:

```
public static void setFieldValue(Object instance, String fieldName, Object value) {
    try {
        Field f = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);

        Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);

        Field theInternalUnsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theInternalUnsafe");
        theInternalUnsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        Object theInternalUnsafe = theInternalUnsafeField.get(null);

        Method offset = Class.forName("jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe").getMethod("objectFieldOffset", Field.class);
        unsafe.putBoolean(offset, 12, true);

        unsafe.putObject(instance, (long) offset.invoke(theInternalUnsafe, f), value);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t come back complaining about crashes or “weird behavior” in your program.

Comment: @Holger I accepted this answer, but not because I will be using it. I did not want to delete the question. Suddenly someone will also look for this information.

Comment: @ЭдуардАртюх that’s exactly why it is important to remind future readers that this code is not a solution but a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2):

`Field::set` method doesn't work for record class fields by design. From the [docs](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8247517),

If the underlying field is final, this Field object has write access if and only if the following conditions are met:

- `setAccessible(true)` has succeeded for this Field object;
- the field is **non-static**; and
- the field's declaring class is **not a hidden class**; and
- the field's declaring class is **not a record class**.

To be able to modify the fields reflectively, convert `Account` from a record class to a regular POJO class. Records are truly immutable, not even reflection will do.

### Account.java

```
public class Account {

    private final Integer id;
    private final String login;
    private final Boolean blocked;

    public Account(Integer id, String login, Boolean blocked) {
        this.id = id;
        this.login = login;
        this.blocked = blocked;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public Boolean getBlocked() {
        return blocked;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking about Java records, but if you really need to change a single field in a record you could user a Kotlin data class which allows you to easily create a copy of the data with just one field changed. The Kotlin class can easily be called from Java

Kotlin data class:

```
data class Account(val id :String, val login: String, val blocked: Boolean) {
    fun setId(id:String) = copy(id = id)
    fun setLogin(login:String) = copy(login = login)
    fun setBlocked(blocked:Boolean) = copy(blocked = blocked)
}
```

Java class:

```
 public class AccountSetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account("oldId", "foo", false);
        account = account.setId("newId");
    }

}
```